# to be fair to myself or to be fair to me?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> To be fair to myself, he could, at times, become a bona fide drone.
>
> To be fair to me, he could, at times, become a bona fide drone.

Is an 'I' not required before using the reflexive pronoun 'myself'?
What is the rule governing when to use 'myself'?

Comment: For other me/myself issues see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443444/should-i-use-me-or-myself-help https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160554/should-i-use-me-or-myself-here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/573224/within-me-or-within-myself and search for *me or myself*

Comment: If you are being fair, it's "myself". If somebody else is being fair, it's "me".

Comment: Comparing 'Being fair to myself', where 'me' is unavailable (assuming one is using self-mitigation ... and I'd rephrase otherwise) adds support to Peter's statement.